# Photo electron effect on free electron

Tags: photoelectric-effect

Suppose there is light of high enough frequency so it causes [photoelectric effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect) (in a piece of metal). Does such light cause photoelectric effect on free electrons as well?

Comment: For free electrons, you have the [Compton scattering process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering).

Comment: @CountIblis: that should be an answer

Comment: [*"The photoelectric effect is the observation that many metals emit electrons when light shines upon them."*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect) - How is it meaningful to ask whether this effect happens for free electrons, when it, *by definition*, happens in metals?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: a sympathetic interpretation would be to ask if light has any interaction with free electrons that is analogous to the photoelectic effect, and this seems to me a reasonable if rather basic question.

Answer (score 7):

The photoelectric effect occurs when an atom (or ion) absorbs the energy of a photon and an electron is emitted. Some of the photon energy is used to liberate the electron, the rest goes into the electron kinetic energy.

The same thing *cannot* happen when light interacts with a free electron (e.g. see [Free electron can't absorb a photon](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/225522/free-electron-cant-absorb-a-photon) ). A simple proof shows that a free electron cannot absorb all the energy of a photon and simultaneously conserve linear momentum.

Instead, *part* of the photon energy is given to the electron and a photon of lower energy is scattered. This is known as the Compton effect.

Comment: How would such a simple proof look like? It doesn't seem obvious to me.. :(

Comment: @Ben https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/225522/free-electron-cant-absorb-a-photon

Answer (score 0):

The photoelectric effect - ejection of electrons from matter due to light - is a phenomenon that occurs when light shines on a piece of metal. I do not think such phenomenon was observed with free electrons in vacuo.

( Compton scattering is often described as if electrons interacting with the light were free, but it actually refers to an experiment where the electrons are bound to nuclei in matter. )

Answer (score 0):

We can prove that photoelectric effect does not happen for free electron.

we look at the hypothetical process in the center-of-mass system, which is defined as that system in which the initial momentum is zero. From the conservation of energy.
E initial = E final

hv +Mc^2  = Mo c^2

( Mo is the rest mass)
( M is the relativistic mass)

or

which implies Mo> M
Since this cannot be true the process can't occur.

The electrons participating in the photoelectric effect are not free. The heavy matter present takes off momentum but absorbs a negligible amount of energy.